# How to load space separate file into pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to load a space separated data into pandas dataframe. If I use `sep='\s+'`, then I get the error `CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 7 fields in line 5, saw 9`

```
df = pd.read_table("data.rpt",sep='\s+',index_col=False)
```

I was able to open this file in Excel using space as a delimiter. How to solve this issue with pandas?

Fist lines of a file:

```
Id IdEvent  Agent   Sist  Group   Con CInt
-- -------  -----   ----  -----   --- ----
18 2016101  B0C     XCX   ROD F   DC  0
19 2016101  A0C     DCX   APT     AD  5
15 2016103  V0C     XCX   ROD S   DC  0
16 2016102  N0C     XCX   ROD     CD  0
```

Comment: You can parse it with regex. Include the file if you can.

Comment: What does line 5 of your data look like?  From the error, it seems like it has more spaces than the previous lines do.  Perhaps one of the fields contains a value with a space in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [read_fwf()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) method:

```
In [125]: pd.read_fwf(fn, skiprows=[1])
Out[125]:
   Id  IdEvent Agent Sist  Group Con  CInt
0  18  2016101   B0C  XCX  ROD F  DC     0
1  19  2016101   A0C  DCX    APT  AD     5
2  15  2016103   V0C  XCX  ROD S  DC     0
3  16  2016102   N0C  XCX    ROD  CD     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `delim_whitespace=True` as an argument.

Comment: I tried it as well. Still getting the error `CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 7 fields in line 5, saw 9`

Comment: Does your file has a header ?

Comment: yes, it has a header and it looks like the next like after the header is `--- -------------- ---` (something like this).

Comment: I would need to set something like: `header=True` and `skip_lines=0`, which means that the first line is header and the next one should be skipped. Is it possible?

Comment: IMO the best way is to skip the first rows composing the header (with skiprows argument).

Comment: I am putting these parameters `delim_whitespace=True,skiprows=0,header=1,index_col=False`, but still the same error.

Comment: try setting `skiprows=5`if 5 is the line at which you have the `--- -------------- ---`

Comment: Can I pass the list of rows? How to do it?

Comment: Do you have a fixed header ? Can you edit your question and post your header ?

Comment: Yes, I posted the first lines from a file.

Comment: Try this : `df = pd.read_csv("data.rpt",delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=2)`

Comment: I think that the problem is that some entries have a content like `Done ABC AR`. I mean, this includes a space. However, why that I can open it in Excel by setting Delimiter = Space?

Comment: I made some prerocessing in VIM and now I can load it into pandas.